# RTP traces repository

Tags: repository, trace, wireshark, rtp

Is there any public RTP repo where can I download a lot of RTP traces (in addition to the ones in example wireshark traces)? Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

www.wiresharkbook.com  Downloads section

http://pcapr.net/browse/voip